# Import MySQL data to excel in format

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel, sms-gateway

i just noob  for mysql, 
i have some data in mysql and i would like to import it to ms excel in format.

let say my data is look like this in mysql

**id     number              msg**
1            1                001#now#and#then
2
         2            002#this#or#that

i would like to automatically split when import msg column to excel

**no     id     status      another        function**
1        1         now               and                    then
2        2         this                or                      that

And i want to put this Save button in php.

Please help...

Thanks,

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is it writing the Excel file? Or is it splitting the msg data into three values? The former can be solved by using one of the many libraries available to write Excel files such as [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com). The latter can be solved by exploding the `msg` column value on "#"

Comment: Hi Mark, i truly dont remember if i ever ask this, actually i want to explode the msg column in mysql into excel...my apologize for leaving your comment irresponsibly...thanks,