# Comparing boolean cells in excel?

Tags: excel, boolean

i have some problem in how to compare boolean cells.

Let say like this

**A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I**

---

1    1    1    1    1    0
1    0    1    1    1    1
0    1    1    0    1    1
0    0    0    1    1    1

---

In cell G2 i need to calculate and compare every 3 celss.

if *"sum"* of **A2:C2 = 3**, then return **0**, but if *"sum"* of **A2:C2 <=2**, then *"sum"* **B2:D2**, if "sum" of **B2:D2 = 3** then **return 1 else 0**

In cell H2 i need to do the same.

if *"sum"* of **B2:D2 = 3**, then return **0**, but if *"sum"* of **B2:D2 <=2**, then *"sum"* **C2:E2**, if "sum" of **C2:E2 = 3** then **return 1 else 0**

and so on

i already try IF, AND, SUM but still not working.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Hi pnuts, sorry for my late response, it works great, just need some adjustment and yeah it did it.... thanks alot for your help...

Comment: my apologize, maybe i forgot if i ever asking [that question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624254/import-mysql-data-to-excel-in-format) ...:(